# Gradient field and flow across a curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Say we have a gradient field $\vec{F}(x, y) = \nabla \phi$ and a closed curve $C$.

We know that the curl $\nabla \times \vec{F}(x,y)$ will be $0$ and the net flow of this field **along** the closed curve $C$ is $0$.

Can we say anything about the net flow **across** the curve?
Can we say anything about the divergence $\nabla \cdot \vec{F}(x,y)$?

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you mean by flow "across" the curve. Do you mean the flow across an open surface which has the curve as boundary? For example, if the curve is a circle, do you mean the flow across the circular surface it encloses? But there is no unique surface that you can define that way.

Comment: By the way, $\nabla \cdot \vec{F} = \nabla \cdot \nabla \phi$ is denoted by $\nabla^2 \phi$, and $\nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$ (or just $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ in the $xy$-plane) is called the Laplacian operator. The differential equation $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ is called the Laplacian differential equation and is of interest in its own right.